# JSON - how to get value in pure JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I can't get any value from my JSON object.

I was trying:

```
console.log(players[0].player.info.position)
```

It return undefined.
What am i doing wrong?

Validator say that JSON in valid.
Here is JSON object:

```
{"players": [
{
  "player": {
    "info": {
      "position": "aaa",
      "shirtNum": 1,
      "positionInfo": "aaa"
    },
    "nationalTeam": {
      "isoCode": "aaa",
      "country": "aaa",
      "demonym": "aaa"
    },
    "age": "221",
    "name": {
      "first": "aaa",
      "last": "aaa"
    },
    "id": 111,
    "currentTeam": {
      "name": "aaa",
      "teamType": "aaa",
      "shortName": "aaa",
      "id": 21
    }
  }
}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have that json in a variable which I call `theThing`. You need to use `theThing` to gain access to your json.

```
var theThing =    JSON.parse('{"players":[{"player":{"info":{"position":"aaa","shirtNum":1,"positionInfo":"aaa"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"aaa","country":"aaa","demonym":"aaa"},"age":"221","name":{"first":"aaa","last":"aaa"},"id":111,"currentTeam":{"name":"aaa","teamType":"aaa","shortName":"aaa","id":21}}}]}');
alert(theThing.players[0].player.info.position);
```

Comment: Yep :). In a few minutes i will be able to do it. You was soo fast with your answer:).

Comment: This answer dangerously misleads newbies to what JSON is, and what JS object is.

Answer (score 0):

Try `JSON.parse()`. JSON itself is a string.

```js
obj = JSON.parse('{"players":[{"player":{"info":{"position":"aaa","shirtNum":1,"positionInfo":"aaa"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"aaa","country":"aaa","demonym":"aaa"},"age":"221","name":{"first":"aaa","last":"aaa"},"id":111,"currentTeam":{"name":"aaa","teamType":"aaa","shortName":"aaa","id":21}}}]}');

console.log(obj['players'][0].player.info.position);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.parse with your json string:

```js
obj = JSON.parse('{"players":[{"player":{"info":{"position":"aaa","shirtNum":1,"positionInfo":"aaa"},"nationalTeam":{"isoCode":"aaa","country":"aaa","demonym":"aaa"},"age":"221","name":{"first":"aaa","last":"aaa"},"id":111,"currentTeam":{"name":"aaa","teamType":"aaa","shortName":"aaa","id":21}}}]}');

console.log(obj['players'][0].player.info.position);
```